# code sign with new provisioning profile in XCode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

How can I make my app to code sign with a new profisioning profile I just added in XCode4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, go to your application's build settings, scroll down to "code signing identity" and select the appropriate provisioning profile.